# HitTestPoint not working, collisions not happening

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs4

I'm trying to create something similar to Impossible Quiz Question 5 (1st quiz). However the hitTestPoint appears to be not reading. I'm not exactly sure where my error is.

Here is my full line of code.

```
stop();

blueTarget.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, mousehandler2);
function mousehandler2(e:MouseEvent):void {
    if (blueTarget.hitTestPoint(mouseX,mouseY,true)) {
        removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, mousehandler2);
        gotoAndStop("lose");
    }
}
nexttButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mousehandler3);
function mousehandler3(e:MouseEvent):void {
    removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mousehandler3);
    MovieClip(root).nextFrame();
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: how if the `stop();` was removed?

Comment: The most common error with the **hiTestPoint** is that method arguments are tricky: https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#hitTestPoint() *The x and y parameters specify a point in the coordinate space of the Stage, not the display object container that contains the display object...*

Comment: @StefansArya When mouse goes over blueTarget, blueTarget disappears and doesn't go to lose screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want the player to lose if he passes the mouse over the blueTarget? If so, you can remove your `if` statement because the mouse over event is already added to the `blueTarget`

Comment: When I took out the `if` statement, and when the mouse went over the blue, the blue screen disappears and doesn't go to my lose screen: stop();

`blueTarget.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, mousehandler2);
function mousehandler2(e:MouseEvent):void {
        removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, mousehandler2);
        gotoAndStop("lose");
    }
}
nexttButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mousehandler3);
function mousehandler3(e:MouseEvent):void {
    removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mousehandler3);
    MovieClip(root).nextFrame();
}`

Comment: I think it's because you're telling the blueTarget to `gotoAndStop("lose")` but I don't know where did you define that. Did you try `MovieClip(root).gotoAndStop("lose")` inside your mouse handler instead?